# Wordpress - Add a page upon activation of plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently making a Wordpress plugin, but I couldn't find an answer to this.

**How do you add a page upon activation of the plugin?**

I have added posts upon activation earlier with the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function, but I can't find a way to insert a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the activation hook for plugins in order to make any actions upon the plugin activation.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activation_hook_callback');

function activation_hook_callback()
  {
   //add the post type and other options in the array for the query
    $page = array(

          'post_status' => 'publish' ,
          'post_title' => 'Page name',
          'post_type' => 'page',
    );  
    //add the page and ID will be saved.
    $the_page_itself = wp_insert_post( $page );

  }
```

This should work.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks. I'll give you the correct answer since you bothered <3

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Wordpress has several `post-types`:

```
Post (Post Type: 'post')
Page (Post Type: 'page')
Attachment (Post Type: 'attachment')
Revision (Post Type: 'revision')
Navigation menu (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')
```

To add a post upon activation of my plugin:

```
function add_page_upon_activation() {
    $arr = array(
        'post_title' => 'title',
        'post_name' => 'slug',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_content' => 'yes, a nice page',
    );
    wp_insert_post($arr);
}
add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'add_page_upon_activation' );
```